# How to remove tap highlight color in Android 4.4.2/chrome

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, webkit

I've read many posts and answers with regard to the question above, but as yet, I haven't come up with an answer that works.

This is my current code:

```
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    outline:none;
}
```

I've also used 'transparent' in place of rgba.

As I pointed out - I'm using Android 4.4.2 on a HTC one, now using Chrome 42.

Nothing I have done has resulted in removing the green overlay. I came across a bug report that implied that the webkit engine is no longer used on this Andriod/Chrome version (probably true as it was on the official site), but if that is the case, how do I remove it?

I can't believe I'm the only one with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS tweak worked perfectly for me using a Galaxy Tab S running 5.0.2. and Moto G phone running 5.1.  You might have a conflict in your CSS.  Hopefully by you got it worked out.

Thanks for the post John!

Comment: This should be a comment. As you don't have enough reputation to comment everywhere so wait until you have achieve this.